# 404 Property not found key / visibility when using patch request Google Drive api v2

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive API (v2) and used to make successful patch requests as explained here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/patch
in order to add a new metadata property (**myNewPr**) into my documents.
However, recently (maybe 1-2 days) I started to receive 404 error messages:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Property not found: key = myNewPr and visibility = PRIVATE",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "property"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Property not found: key = myNewPr and visibility = PRIVATE"
 }
}
```

Any ideas ? When I am testing by using insert (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/insert) it seems to work.

Comment: At least someone now has changed documentation.. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/patch

Comment: Well, are you trying to use patch to update a property, or create a property? From the error you show, property creation is not supported via patch requests.

Comment: For the past 1.5 years I used to do a patch to update/create a property. From yesterday it seems that the API is not supporting patch for creating new property (also documentation was changed yesterday). I was wondering what happened.